# Elixir implementation of ngram

Tags: elixir

I want to develop a very small script that reads a sentence and generates in the console an output of n-gram figure.

This is an example

```
Example
"Show me the code."
Returns
[
  "Show",
  "Show me",
  "Show me the",
  "Show me the code",
  "me",
  "me the",
  "me the code",
  "the",
  "the code",
  "code"
]
```

This is my code:

```
defmodule M do
  def main do
    sentence = IO.gets("What is the sentence : ")
    ls = String.split(sentence)
    lsSize = length(ls)
    Enum.each 0..lsSize , fn(x) ->
      posNew = x+1
      IO.puts Enum.at(ls,x)
      Enum.each posNew..lsSize , fn(y) ->
        currentWord = Enum.join([Enum.at(ls,x),  Enum.at(ls,y)], " ")
        IO.puts(currentWord)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Only thing I get is:

```
What is the sentence : one two three
one
one two
one three
one
two
two three
two
three
three
```

Can you please  help me with this? I don't understand why the value of currentCode is not updated outside the Enum.each and gets reset. 
I am new to erlang and Elixir and that is why i fail to understand the problem in this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That's because you are only joining two words at a time.** Your call to Enum.join here only joins the words at `x` and `y` positions, and not all the words between them:

```ex
Enum.join([Enum.at(ls,x),  Enum.at(ls,y)], " ")
```

You need to join all words in that range:

```ex
Enum.join(Enum.slice(ls, x, y), " ")
```

---

Besides that, your code still has some other bugs. **Here's how you can break down the code in to smaller methods to achieve what you're trying to do:**

```ex
defmodule NGram do
  def run do
    "Enter sentence: "
    |> IO.gets
    |> String.trim
    |> String.split(" ")
    |> build
    |> Enum.map(&IO.puts/1)
    :ok
  end

  def build(words) do
    words
    |> pre_walk
    |> Enum.map(&String.split(&1, " "))
    |> Enum.map(&post_walk/1)
    |> List.flatten
  end

  defp pre_walk(words) do
    length = length(words)

    Enum.map(0..(length-1), fn i ->
      words
      |> Enum.slice(i, length)
      |> Enum.join(" ")
    end)
  end

  defp post_walk(subwords) do
    Enum.map(1..length(subwords), fn i ->
      subwords
      |> Enum.slice(0, i)
      |> Enum.join(" ")
    end)
  end
end
```

Comment: Alright, I understand now what you mean. But by doing the slice, I end up with:  
one
one
one two
one two three
two
two three
two three
three
three

Comment: The issue with Enum.reduce (it was your initial comment too, then you deleted it I think) is that I don't understand the parameters in terms of how exactly should I use it to generate the ngram. Can you please help with this?

Comment: Updated the code to use a simpler example with `Enum.map` instead of `Enum.reduce`.